# Weighted Maximum 3-DIMENSIONAL-MATCHING with restricted weights (Approx Algo)

Tags: algorithms, approximation

If the weights of the weighted 3-DIMENSIONAL-MATCHING problem are restricted to let's say, 1 and 2, is there a possibility to reduce this case to the unweighted 3-DIMENSIONAL-MATCHING problem?
(Because for the unweighted version, there is a (1.5+$\epsilon$)-approximation<sup>1</sup> algorithm, for the weighted version, there is only a 2-approx<sup>2,3</sup> algorithm)

---

References:

1. [unweighted ($1.5+\epsilon$-approx)](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node275.html#HurSch89)
2. [weighted ($2+\epsilon$-approx)](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node275.html#ArkHas97)
3. [weighted ($2$-approx)](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~yhchan/thesis.pdf) by CHAN, Yuk Hei, 2009

Comment: Good links (specially 2009 one), thanks.

Comment: So you need reductions that maintain approximation errors?

Comment: Well, I can't even think of a reduction that doesn't. Of course, a reduction that maintains approximation would be great.

Comment: @user1464: Well, some NP-complete problems admit [FPTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPTAS) while others don't, so normal polynomial reduction destroys approximation bounds in general.

Comment: Also see Section 4 of _Three Dimensional Axial Assignment Problems with Decomposable Cost Coefficients_, Discrete Applied Mathematics 65, 1996, 123-139